# How can I pass data from "didSelectRowAt" to another VC without presenting it or a segue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What I basically want is I want to press on a row in my `TableViewController` which then takes, for example, the **text** that the row has and passes it to a `ViewController` that is currently not present. Like when you click on a song in the **Spotify app** and it plays it without presenting anything but the song details are shown in the mini-player.

Does anyone have a clue how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do that but you need to initialize your View Controller first for you to access its properties like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationVc") as? DestinationVc
    vc?.text = "TextToBePassed"
}
```

And there it is without presenting it but I don't get it why you don't want to present or show it but that's how it is done based on your question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the UI via `XIB` or `programatically` then follow this approach:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let nextVC = NextViewController()
  nextVC.text = model?[indexPath.row].text // If you are using model or if you have stored the data in the array then nextVC.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]["text"]    
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC,animated: true)

}
```

Also, in the `NextViewController`, you have to add text. Like this:

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

  var text = String()

  //MARK:- View Life Cycle

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     print(text) //This will print the text passed from previous VC
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = NextViewController()
    vc.title = "\(Title)"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated: true)
}
```

Using this method can help you in passing the data to another Controller without using segue.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is for iOS as the question doesn't specify.

In the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method in your `UITableViewDelegate`, you can grab the cell's text with

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel?.text // cell: String?
```

You can then assign this to a global variable if you wish, or if you maintain a reference to the non-present view controller, you can give it a property to store this text and assign it before you call `performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?)`.